# Rails keeps changing my string "?" into "%3F"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helpermethods

Basicaly I just want to insert this `+ "?direction=desc"` in helper method.

But once it parses it comes out like this..

```
/organizations/search?order_by=contactable%3Fdirection%3Ddesc
```

Anyone know a way around this?

My Helper Method:

```
def search_sort(name, sort_by, order = 'asc')
  link_to(name, url_for(:overwrite_params => { :order_by => sort_by + "?direction=desc" :page => nil }), :class => 'selected save_pushstate')
  ...
```

I know what you're thinking. Just add :order into it. The problem being is that I 'm using an AJAX history saver from #175 of railscasts.

```
$(".save_pushstate").live("click", function() {
  $.setFragment({"order_by" : $.queryString($(this).attr('href')).order_by});
  //$.setFragment({"direction" : $.queryString($(this).attr('href')).direction});
    return false;
});
```

And it rewrites my url to just one "fragment". I can't have two! So I decided that if I can just add the direction param in the href hard-coded, it could deal with this whole mess.

Comment: This is likely done by a URI.escape call somewhere.  Exactly what's doing it is hard to say without seeing a bit of actual code.  And do you really want another '?' in that query?

Comment: see answer below (about html_safe). strings on rails 3 are now scaped by default, and need to be flagged as safe before they are rendered as is on the page to prevent XSS

Comment: Have you checked out the latest railscasts on AJAX history state? It might prove useful for you, as it specifically refers to episode 175 as well: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state

Comment: that's where i started and ended up going backwards from there. unless there's  something dreadflly obvious that i'm missing.

Comment: Something I just realized: you should be using & instead of ? in your appended string.

Comment: Hmm.. it should work either way. But it still doesn't excape the XSS. Thanks though! ;)

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you leave out :escape => false, url_for should be doing the html escaping by default.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
+ "?direction=desc".html_safe
```

Edit:
Since you're using rails 2.3.5, try this:

```
def search_sort(name, sort_by, order = 'asc')
  link_to(name, url_for(:overwrite_params => { :order_by => sort_by + "?direction=desc" :page => nil }, :escape => false), :class => 'selected save_pushstate')
  ...
```

Note the ":escape => false" in url_for.

Edit2:
After reading this:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/80381

Specifically this excerpt:

> I think this is where the confusion is
>   arising. There are two different kinds
>   of escaping going on.
>
> It sounds like you're talking about
>   the URL encoding that uses '%xx' to
>   represent special characters.
>
> However, the html_escape function does
>   something completely different. It
>   takes a string and turns '&' into
>   '&' and '<' into '<', etc., so
>   that it can go into HTML without being
>   interpreted as literal '&'s and '<'s.
>
> Escaping special characters in URLs
>   using the '%xx' scheme is mandatory,
>   otherwise they are not valid URLs.

I've realized that the 'escaping' that you see happening is url encoding, and it shouldn't affect your query/sorting, etc.  You can test it out by taking the encoded url and typing it into your browser.

:escape => false disable html escaping, which means dangerous characters get converted to display codes, such as '&' into '&' and '<' into '<', etc.,

And the "?" in your append should be "&":

```
+ "&direction=desc"
```

Hope this helps.  =)

Comment: i think that might be only for rails 3? i'm using rails 2.3.5. any alternatives?

Comment: What does your helper method look like?

Comment: I think its around in some form - does “TEST”.html_safe! work for you?  http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/5/24/ruby-on-rails-2-3-7-released

Comment: Try out the alternative solution I've posted for rails 2.3.5.  =)

Comment: @clemensp, yah that :escape gives me the same bug still. went through the other tutorial a few more times.. i don't think its any better of a solution for this..

Comment: @clemensp, yah i'm using firefox and the latest RailsCast won't work on it. I get a `history.pushstate is not a function` . Doesn't seem to be a way around it.